# Qt udp socket, what will trigger the socket's readyRead signal?

Tags: c++, qt, udp

If I bind my udp socket like this:

```
connectState = socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 14550);
```

then my understanding is that all the device on my LAN with port 14550 will trigger the readyRead signal if it writes something out using UDP.

Am I correct? If some device is on prot 12345, then it won't trigger readyRead signal?
And is it possible to bind to only a specific address range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I have the feeling you mix up AnyAddress with broadcast

> then my understanding is that all the device on my LAN with port 14550
>   will trigger the readyRead signal if it writes something out using
>   UDP.

No. It triggers a readyRead when it sends an UDP packet on any address of your server it can reach. The UDP package has to be addressed to your computer. In this case `::Any` means any interface even the virtual 127.0.0.1.

The UDP package has to be send to the selected port.

> And is it possible to bind to only a specific address range?

As far as I know NO. In all OS I know of  `::Any` translates to 0.0.0.0 which is a  special address telling the OS to "listen on any available interface" If you want to exclude some you have to somehow determine the list of IPs your interested in and build a collection of QUdpSocket to listen to.

Comment: So, a simple example, if my PC's address is 192.168.1.10, my device that send out udp packet's address is 192.168.1.20, and I call the socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 14550) on my PC, will my PC be able to receive the packet and trigger the readRead signal? Or is it still depends on what address my device is sending the packet to?

Comment: The device explicitly has to send the packet to 192.168.1.10. Otherwise it won't reach your PC. What you seem to be after is the broadcast address. If you listen on the special broadcast address you will receive any UDP packet send on broadcast by any devices. But all other PCs listening on that address will also receive the same package (hence the name). Punchline: your device needs to know the target address. Thats the reason why e.g. routers or DSL modems are often configured via broadcast addresses. Your install software listens to broadcast and the device sends out these packages.